# Share cookie between domains

Tags: http, cookies

I have a cookie generated on a domain www.foo.bar that I need to share with another website located on www.something.com.bar.

Both sites are hosted on the same server.

Can I do that, and if yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot share cookies across domains.  The browser will only send a cookie to the domain (or sub-domains there of) that initially set it.

Read up on the [Same origin policy / Cookie policy](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs261/fa17/scribe/web-security-1.pdf)